# grep command to search for a pattern in multiple files and list the files ordering by date

Tags: shell

I have a requirement to search for a pattern in multiple files and get the latest file for further processing. I am trying to do this in a shell script. I was trying to do it as follows

```
file=`grep -lh <pattern> <file_name> | tail -1`
```

But grep is listing the files as in a `ls` and not as in `ls -lrt`. I have tried the following command

```
ls -lrt `grep -l <pattern> <file name>`
```

But I'm not able to incorporate this command in the shell script.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is ***much*** faster. Whereas the other answers `grep` **all** the files, this searches the newest ones first and stops as soon as it finds the pattern.

This one-liner captures the result in a variable:

```
file=$(while read file; do grep pattern "$file" >/dev/null;[[ $? ]]; then echo "$file"; break; fi; done < <(find $startdir -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@:%p\n"|sort -nr|cut -d: -f2-))
```

Here is a Bash script version that is easier to read:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read file
do
    grep pattern "$file" > /dev/null
    if [[ $? ]]
    then
        echo "$file"
        break
    fi
done < <(find $startdir -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@:%p\n" |
            sort -nr |
            cut -d: -f2-)
```

Comment: +1 Looks like it should also handle spaces in filenames.

Comment: True. But not newlines. ~shudder~

Answer (score 0):

you can pipe the output of grep to xargs to use ls -lrt before piping through tail

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
ls -lrt|awk '{print $9}'|xargs -n1 grep <string>|tail -n1|awk '{print $1}'
```

You may need to change which variables in awk get printed, depending on your implementation of ls and grep.

Basically, sort the files first, then look for the string, then take the last result.

Answer (score 0):

```
bluerain ~ # ls -lrt `grep -l a *.sh `
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 315 2007-01-20 17:43 twopass.sh
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  86 2007-04-21 16:23 hd_down.sh
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 245 2009-09-10 19:47 pspenc.sh
    -rwxr--r-- 1 root root  95 2009-09-10 19:50 psp2.sh 
bluerain ~ # kk=`grep -l a *.sh` 
bluerain ~ # bb=` ls -rt $kk | tail -1` 
bluerain ~ # echo $bb psp2.sh 
bluerain ~ # echo $kk hd_down.sh psp2.sh pspenc.sh twopass.sh
```

so use the following:

```
tempvar=`grep -l <pattern> *(for all files in the directory)`
file=`ls -rt $tempvar | tail 1`
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, `grep` should not be re-sorting the filenames you pass to it. If you are passing them explicitly, it will print the output in the same order as the list of files you pass it. However, if you are passing a wildcard, you are correct that your shell will expand that wildcard in lexical order (which is basically what `ls` defaults to, as you noted).

After looking at the other suggestions, I offer the following:

```
file=`ls -t --quoting-style=shell "dir" | xargs grep -l "regex" | head -n 1`
```

I think this meets your requirements, and addresses concerns raised by others as follows:

1. You can use `ls -t` without `-l`, so there's no need to parse the output of `ls -l` with `awk` or `cut` just to get the filename.
2. Don't reverse the sort order of `ls`. Using `ls -t` puts the newest files first, and grabbing the first one with `head` will short-circuit the pipeline as soon as the first matching file is found (so you search the minimal list of files necessary to find a match).
3. Piping to `xargs` effectively lets you search an unlimited number of files without running into the maximum command line length, and does so without looping.
4. Using `ls --quoting-style=shell` quotes filenames with single quotes as needed, so filenames with embedded spaces or control characters are handled properly.

Please note that `--quoting-style` is a GNU extension and is not likely to work with a non-GNU `ls`. You should be fine on Linux. The following is more portable, but adds a call to `sed` to quote the filenames, so there's a little more overhead:

```
file=`ls -t "dir" | sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/' | xargs grep -l "regex" | head -n 1`
```